# PHP Create WSDL file using XSD or XML

Tags: php, xml, web-services, xsd, wsdl

I have created a webservice using PHP and output XML as the webservice response when ever i get request.

I have tried to generate WSDL for the webservice. But i didnt find and opensource classes for wsdl generation from XSD or from XML.

With help of some online portal i can able to generate XSD (from XML the out put).

How Can i create WSDL through PHP when I dont use any protocol like SOAP? is there any tutorial for the generation.

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to generate WSDL if you are not planning to use SOAP?

Comment: But the webservice reader needs WSDL for there usage thats why i am trying hard to create it.. But i came to know the face that WSDL is needed when i use some protocols? Is that right? @ValentinRodygin